# Coordinate Vector Procedure

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

**My question:**

> Is there more procedural way to find a coordinate vector?

Looking at past posts:

- This post just reduces the known transformations $\vec{v_1} → T(\vec{v_1})$ and $\vec{v_2} → T(\vec{v_3})$ to a linear system of equations with respect to the basis vectors for each $T(\vec{v})$, and uses elimintion: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3029692/1098426

  - Only reducing the unknown vectors to component form gives two equations in two variables (i.e., $\mathbf{e_1}$ and $\mathbf{e_2}$) even though it is somewhat confusing to see component and bracket notation mixed.

So, here is my good faith attempt to do that more systematically.

---

For example: We are given $T:[2,3] → [4,3]$ and $T:[4,5] → [6,6]$. To find $T([6,7])=[x,y]$, we say the new basis vectors are $\mathbf{e_1}$ and $\mathbf{e_2}$, and you also say the old vectors are $\mathbf{b_1}$ and $\mathbf{b_2}$. So, we want $x$ and $y$ where $T(6\mathbf{e_1}+7\mathbf{e_2})= x\mathbf{b_1} + y\mathbf{b_2}$. Then we solve for $\mathbf{e_1}$ and $\mathbf{e_2}$.

$4\mathbf{e_1}+3\mathbf{e_2}= 2\mathbf{b_1} + 3\mathbf{b_2}$

$6\mathbf{e_1}+6\mathbf{e_2}= 4\mathbf{b_1} + 5\mathbf{b_2}$

So, using elimination, subtract $\text{eqn. 2}- (2 \times \text{eqn. 1})$.

$\Rightarrow 2\mathbf{e_1} = 2(2\mathbf{b_1} + 3\mathbf{b_2}) - (4\mathbf{b_1} + 5\mathbf{b_2})$

$\Rightarrow 2\mathbf{e_1} = (2\cdot2-4)\mathbf{b_1} + (2\cdot3-5)\mathbf{b_2}$

$\Rightarrow \mathbf{e_1} = \frac 23 \mathbf{b_1} + \frac 13 \mathbf{b_2}$

Then, substituting $\frac 23 \mathbf{b_1} + \frac 13 \mathbf{b_2}$ for $\mathbf{e_1}$ back into $\text{eqn. 2}$

$\Rightarrow 6\cdot(\frac 23 \mathbf{b_1} + \frac 13 \mathbf{b_2})+6\mathbf{e_2}= 4\mathbf{b_1} + 5\mathbf{b_2}$

$\Rightarrow 6\mathbf{e_2}= 4\mathbf{b_1} + 5\mathbf{b_2} - 6\cdot(\frac 23 \mathbf{b_1} + \frac 13 \mathbf{b_2})$

$\Rightarrow \mathbf{e_2} = \frac 23 \mathbf{b_1} + \frac 13 \mathbf{b_2}$

So, we have found $\mathbf{e_1}$ and $\mathbf{e_2}$ such that:

$\Rightarrow \begin{align} \mathbf{e_1} &= 0\mathbf{b_1} + \frac 12 \mathbf{b_2} \\ \mathbf{e_2} &= \frac 23 \mathbf{b_1} + \frac 13 \mathbf{b_2} \end{align}$

Note: after the fact, I see that Gaussian elimination gives:

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 4&3&2&3 \\ 6&6&4&5 \end{bmatrix}$
$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 1&0& 0 & \frac 12 \\ 0&1&\frac 23 & \frac 13\end{bmatrix}$

Having found $\mathbf{e_1}$ and $\mathbf{e_2}$ in terms of $\mathbf{b_1}$ and $\mathbf{b_2}$, we can use Gaussian elimination.

$\Rightarrow \begin{align} 6\mathbf{e_1} &= 0\mathbf{b_1} + \frac 12 \mathbf{b_2} \\ 7\mathbf{e_2} &= \frac 23 \mathbf{b_1} + \frac 13 \mathbf{b_2} \end{align}$

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac 12 & 6 \\ \frac 23 & \frac 13 & 7 \end{bmatrix}$
$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 8 \\ 0 & 1 & 9 \end{bmatrix}$

$ \Rightarrow 6\mathbf{e_1}+7\mathbf{e_2} = 8\mathbf{b_1} + 9\mathbf{b_2}$

$ \Rightarrow T([6,7]) = [8,9]$

---

Distilled, this is **my Procedure**:

1. Given two transformations (two vectors in domain, two in range): convert vectors in domain (basis $\{\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2}\}$) and range (basis $\{\mathbf{b_1},\mathbf{b_2}\}$) to linear combinations of basis vectors.
2. Set up a system of equations with the linear combinations for the two given vectors in domain of $T$, two given in range of $T$.
3. Solve for "new" basis vectors ($\{\mathbf{b_1},\mathbf{b_2}\}$ in range of $T$) as linear combinations of "old" basis vectors ($\{\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2}\}$ in domain of $T$)—using use Gaussian elimination or any sufficient method.
4. Set up a system of equations so that each component of the desired vector in range of $T$ is expressed as linear combination of basis $\{\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2}\}$ in range of $T$
5. Solve for values of new basis vectors using Gaussian elimination or any other sufficient technique.

---

Note: part of my confusion may be scenarios where $\{\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2}\}$, and  $\{\mathbf{b_1},\mathbf{b_2}\}$, where $T( \{\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2}\} ) = \{\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2}\} $ are all given, but they must be converted to coordinate vectors to find the matrix of $T$ rather than simply a change of coordinate matrix. I might make a separate post about that eventually. **I just want to focus on asking about the procedure for change of coordinate matrices in this post.**

And, I hope my work above shows my good faith attempt at this question. Apologies for the length.